# ambiguous pyinstaller error "Python library not found"

Tags: python, pyinstaller, ioerror

I'm trying to use pyinstaller to create a .exe of a python script when I run

```
python pyinstaller /path/to/my/script
```

I get the error:

```
IOError: Python library not found!
```

All I could find on this problem was http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/169 which mentioned something about using dynamic versus static libraries for python.  I couldn't find anything about what that means, could someone tell me what that means and/or how I can stop this error?